# Is rviz a good display interface for a simulator

Tags: simulation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello all,

I am developing a project in which I need to have a simulator of the robot for the user, so I would like to integrate the simulator display of Rviz in my interface,

is there anyway in ROS in which I can input the commands by commandline for example or which I an manipulate their code to get it inside my gui ?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10742/is-rviz-a-good-display-interface-for-a-simulator/) by [Shamma](https://answers.ros.org/users/376/shamma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-07-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Rviz is a visualizer, if you are looking for a simulator in row, then you should look into `gazebo`, see the wiki here http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo. OpenRAVE also provides a good simulator and is well documented [here](http://openrave.programmingvision.com/) with row support available as well.

It would help if you clarify your needs further.

---

Originally posted by [makokal](https://answers.ros.org/users/31/makokal/) with karma: 1295 on 2011-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4